# Show that ($\lnot$q $\implies$ p) $\implies$ (p $\implies$ $\lnot$q) $\equiv$ ($\lnot$p $\lor$ $\lnot$q) using the conditional-disjunction equivalence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Conditional-disjunction equivalence:

> (p $\implies$ q) $\equiv$ ($\lnot$p $\lor$ q)

To show:

> ($\lnot$q $\implies$ p) $\implies$ (p $\implies$ $\lnot$q) $\equiv$ ($\lnot$p $\lor$ $\lnot$q)

Attempt:

> $\lnot$($\lnot$q $\implies$ p) $\lor$ (p $\implies$ $\lnot$q) by conditional-disjuction equivalence
>
> $\equiv$ $\lnot$($\lnot$($\lnot$q) $\lor$ p) $\lor$ ($\lnot$p $\lor$ $\lnot$q) by conditional-disjunction equivalence
>
> $\equiv$ $\lnot$(q $\lor$ p) $\lor$ ($\lnot$p $\lor$ $\lnot$q) by double negation law
>
> $\equiv$ ($\lnot$q $\land$ $\lnot$p) $\lor$ ($\lnot$p $\lor$ $\lnot$q) by DeMorgan law

I am stuck at the last step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there.

$(\neg q\wedge\neg p)\vee(\neg p\vee\neg q)\equiv[(\neg q\wedge\neg p)\vee\neg p]\vee\neg q$ by the associativity of $\vee$.

$\color{red}{[(\neg q\wedge\neg p)\vee\neg p]}\vee\neg q\equiv\neg p\vee \neg q$ by absorption on the red term.

Comment: I Never saw ($\lnot$q $\lor$ $\lnot$p) as a single term to which the a law can be applied. Thank you.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer consider accepting it by clicking the tick-mark button next to it.